# Post with parameters using HttpWebRequest in C#

Tags: c#, post, httpwebrequest

Having the following code:

```
                var request = HttpWebRequest.Create("https://api.channeladvisor.com/oauth2/token");
            request.ContentType = "text/html";               
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.Headers.Add("cache-control","no-cache");
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64Translator.ToBase64(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII, devKey+":"+sharedSecret));          

            string postData = " grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=a12SL1bHhJwerxM2NFth2efZw0yIW7462kAhR43UCJA";

            var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
            request.ContentLength = data.Length;

            using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }

            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

What's wrong? I can't do the request but I can using external programs like Postman. Do you see anything wrong in the header?

```
Error: "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: Try comparing your request with a good request using Fiddler.

Answer (score 2):

Your content type should be application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

```
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add it!

Comment: I did it! Error: "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."

Comment: guess: you have a leading space in PostData.

Comment: Hehe I tried adding an space (1 of my test... ) but wihtout space still not work :'(